# How to use Kendo for Angular 2 in a Visual Studio 2015 Asp.Net Core SPA

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, kendo-ui-angular2

I scaffolded a new Asp.net Core Angular 2 SPA with that [Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack) and want to evaluate Kendo for ng2 now but I failed. Especially I get unexpressive exceptions when I import the GridModule.

How can I get started with Kendo for ng2 in that VS2015 project?

Installed `Node` and `npm` version:

```
C:\Windows\system32>node -v v6.9.4

C:\Windows\system32>npm -v 4.1.2
```

**Exception**:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed
> because of error: Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\dev\ASP.NET-CORE\aspnetcore-k2-master\ClientApp\dist\main-server'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>
> Full [Stacktrace](https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/aspnetcore-k2/issues/1) is here.

I followed that [Kendo Grid](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#toc-installation) documenting​ when I got that exception in the Web UI on start.

**NOTE**: The [Kendo Button](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#toc-set-up-the-angular-2-project) Getting Started guide worked properly!

Thanks in advance for your valuable support

Answer (score 0):

This probably has more to do with the starter pack you used than it does the Kendo grid.  I'm using the same starter.  When including new vendor files such as Kendo, you have to make sure you re-generate the vendor file by running the following:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

You can find more documentation on Steve Sanderson's blog:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

If that doesn't fix it, there is a discussion on this topic here:

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/363

Comment: I followed again that tutorial: http://developer.telerik.com/products/kendo-ui/single-project-full-stack-angular/ . At first start I got that Exception:
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module '@progress/kendo-angular-intl'  . I added that package "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "*" in package.json. Now I get that Exception: Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function
at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (C:\Source\VSTS\AspNet.Core.Playground\TruckerWebApp\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:2118:51)

Comment: Did you regenerate the vendor.js file after adding the kendo package as I mentioned above or look at the discussion I listed above?

Comment: I did that. I sent you an email